# Javascript How to get the properties of an object property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the properties of an object. one of the properties is an object.

```
let myBlog = {
    title: 'My First Blog',
    body: 'This is the first article that blah lorem lorem lorem blah',
    author: 'Koko Bleh Bleh',
    views: 0,
    comments: {
        author: 'TheLegend27',
        body: 'The legendary commentator'
    },
    isLive: false
};

function showBlog(blog)
{
    for(let key in blog)
    {

        if( typeof key !== 'object')
        {
            console.log(key + ': ' + blog[key]);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(key);
            for(let key2 in key)
            {
                console.log(key2 + ': ' + key[key2]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As I was iterating using loop to display the properties and values, the object property named 'comments' is just displaying:
'comment [object object]'

but I want to display it as:
'comment 
author: value
body: some body'

Comment: Your real issue is `key[key2]`. You probably meant `blog[key][key2]`. But how about using recursion... `else { showBlog(blog[key]) }`

Comment: Also, your `else` condition is never running because `key` is **always** a string. You probably meant `if (typeof blog[key] !== 'object')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yon need to check `typeof blog[key]` (the value) and not `typeof
   key` (the key).
2. Yon need to write`blog[key][key2]` insted of `key[key2]`.
3. Better to use: `blog[key].toString() !== "[object Object]"` because, `Date`, `Array` and `null` are also `Object`.

```js
var myBlog = {
    title: 'My First Blog',
    body: 'This is the first article that blah lorem lorem lorem blah',
    author: 'Koko Bleh Bleh',
    views: 0,
    comments: {
        author: 'TheLegend27',
        body: 'The legendary commentator'
    },
    isLive: false
};

function showBlog(blog) {
    for (let key in blog) {
        if (blog[key].toString() !== "[object Object]") {
            console.log(key + ': ' + blog[key]);
        } else {
            console.log(key + ':');
            for (let key2 in blog[key]) {
                console.log(`  ${key2}: ${blog[key][key2]}` );
            }
        }

    }
}
console.log(showBlog(myBlog))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're coercing object to string here

```
console.log(key + ': ' + blog[key]);
```

which is why it is printing `comment [object object]`

```js
let myBlog = {
  title: 'My First Blog',
  body: 'This is the first article that blah lorem lorem lorem blah',
  author: 'Koko Bleh Bleh',
  views: 0,
  comments: {
    author: 'TheLegend27',
    body: 'The legendary commentator'
  },
  isLive: false
};

function showBlog(blog) {
  for (let key in blog) {

    if (typeof key !== 'object') {
      console.log(key + ': ', blog[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(key);
      for (let key2 in key) {
        console.log(key2 + ': ', key[key2]);
      }
    }

  }
}
showBlog(myBlog)
```

Comment: Your code never gets to to `else` because you check the type of the `key` and not the `value`

Comment: @ZivBen-Or it's op's code, as the question is related to why it showing `comment [object object]` and clearly it mention the reason for that

Answer (score 1):

Summarising my comments...

1. Your `else` condition is never running because `key` is **always** a string. You probably meant `if (typeof blog[key] !== 'object')`
2. Since `key` is a string, `for (let key2 in key)` and `key[key2]` won't be what you want. You probably meant `blog[key]`. But how about using recursion... `else { showBlog(blog[key]) }`

```js
let myBlog = {
    title: 'My First Blog',
    body: 'This is the first article that blah lorem lorem lorem blah',
    author: 'Koko Bleh Bleh',
    views: 0,
    comments: {
        author: 'TheLegend27',
        body: 'The legendary commentator'
    },
    isLive: false
};

function showBlog(blog)
{
    for(let key in blog)
    {

        if( typeof blog[key] !== 'object')
        {
            console.log(key + ': ' + blog[key]);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(key);
            showBlog(blog[key]) // recursively call
        }
    }
}

showBlog(myBlog)
```

Comment: Better to use: blog[key].toString() !== "[object Object]" because, Date, Array and null are also Object.

Comment: @ZivBen-Or very good point. I hope OP also checks [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784002/283366)

Answer (score 0):

We can use this simple code which results like

title : My First Blog

body : This is the first article that blah lorem lorem lorem blah

author : Koko Bleh Bleh

views : 0

comments author : TheLegend27

comments body : The legendary commentator

isLive : false

```
function displayObjectValues(myObj, parentObjKey = '') {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
        if (typeof value == 'object') {
            displayObjectValues(value, key);
        } else {
            console.log(`${parentObjKey} ${key} : ${value}`);
        }
    }
}
```